# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a vb.net application in which I'm getting error "
A first chance exception of type `'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'` occurred in `System.Data.dll"` I dont know how to solve this error and there are 4 fields in tables

1. o_id primary key auto increment by 1
2. `c_id` static
3. owner_name `varchar()`
4. investment

   ```
   Dim connetionString As String

   Dim cnn As SqlConnection

   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand


   connetionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\javed\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

   cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

   Try

       cnn.Open()
       MsgBox("Connection is Open ! ")
       cmd.Connection = cnn
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO owner_detail(c_id, o_name, investment) values(@cid,'" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')"
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       MsgBox("Data is Successfully Inserted! ")
       cnn.Close()

   Catch ex As Exception

       MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")

   End Try
   ```

Comment: [What is a First Chance Exception?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) ... "First chance exception messages most often do not mean there is a problem in the code."

Comment: You should check what the SqlException is by debugging your code so as to know where exactly is the error. Try debugging and check the values of all parameters just before it makes the database call, and then see what bit of SQL it tries to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not adding the parameter @cid anywhere.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cid", SqlDbType.Int))
cmd.Parameters("@cid").Value = Idvalue
```